# error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8

Tags: node.js, forever

I'am using node js and forever install on it

When i reload my page in the browser . Igot this error

```
 at Function.app.listen (/var/nodejs_conference/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:532:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/nodejs_conference/bin/www:11:18)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

What is the possible problem?

thanks :)